# MicrosoftGraph Delta API filter and orderby not working

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, delta

I tried to get drive changes(ACL, Edit and Create document, etc.,) of **OneDrive for Business** for a particular user using **delta endpoint** of MicrosoftGraph API. I have tried the following URI to get the latest document changes.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime+desc&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime+gt+cast%28%272016-07-10%27%2C+Edm.DateTimeOffset%29

In the result of the above call, the filter is not working and the sorting is in ASC order instead of DESC.

Is there any mistake in the above URI? Please help me in this.

Comment: Delta doesn't support filter or order by, so those parameters are being ignored. I've created a [pull request to the docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/641) to make that more clear. The pattern for using delta expects that you use the @odata.deltaLink value to retrieve changes between calls, instead of setting a date filter.

Comment: @RyanGregg, Thanks for the response. I will use the "@odata.deltaLink" to get the changes between two calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the updated documentation [Microsoft Graph delta for OneDrive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta#optional-query-parameters) doesn't support to *$filter* and *$orderby*.

Thanks [Ryan Gregg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491656/ryan-gregg) for making the changes to the documentation.